# WooCommerce - Reset quantity input field when variation changes

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

Is there a way or a plugin to reset quantity input field every time a user changes the variation? I searched but i didn't find something similar or any hook.

I tried the following jQuery event but it doesn't seem to fire

```
function variation_select_change() {
global $woocommerce;
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
            alert( "Options changed" );
            } )
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset quantity input field to 1 when variation changes on product detail page use below code. you can set default quantity from  `jQuery("[name='quantity']").val(1);`.   i have tested and it is working fine for me.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'variation_change_update_qty' ); 
function variation_change_update_qty() { 
   if (is_product()) { 
      ?> 
      <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
                jQuery("[name='quantity']").val(1);
            } )
            });
     </script> 
      <?php 
   } 
}
```

let me know is this works for you!

Comment: Great! It Works! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you're welcome!